# Subclassing codable class

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have subclass(`BaseResponse`) of `Decodable` with some parameters for json parsing. And I created a subclass(`UserResponse`) of `BaseResponse`, but I get a runtime exception in code without any explanatory error. 
this is my code:

```
class BaseResponse: Decodable {

    var code:     ResultCode?
    var asanCode: AsanResultCode?
    var message: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case asanCode = "AsanResultCode"
        case message = "Message"
    }

}

class UserResponse: BaseResponse {

    var userInfo: UserInfo?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userInfo = "Info"
    }

}
```

And this is the error (`data == UserResponse`):
[image]

And exception I get in `let code = data.code` part

Comment: Please show some more code. What is `data`?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I wrote above the image, data is UserResponse

Comment: But is it `UserResponse`? Or `UserResponse!`? Need some more information about the "situation" to see what's possibly going wrong...

Comment: Be aware that `Codable` does not support inheritance. If you want to decode also the properties of the base class you have to write a custom initializer.

Comment: @vadian thank you. I already read about it. You can write this as answer, I will accept it

Comment: is userInfo type Decodable ?